# python merge multiple excel files with multiple spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel

i want to merge the sheet form different excel files together, so i can do sum up with sheet1, sheet2 ect.. but now i can only put the sheets in one workbook separately...any helps? Thanks advance.

here's my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
path_read =r'D:\merge'

list_dfs = []
data = pd.DataFrame()

for f in glob.glob(path_read + "/*.xls"):
    sheets = pd.ExcelFile(f).sheet_names    
    for i,sheet in enumerate(sheets):
        df = pd.read_excel(f, sheetname=sheets[i])        
        data = data.append(df)                
        list_dfs.append(data)
        data = pd.DataFrame()

xls_path = r'D:\mytable.xlsx'

def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xls_path)
    for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % n)
    writer.save()
```

save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path)

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to put all those sheets from different workbooks together into one sheet?

Comment: Without completely understanding your question (what did you expect, what did you get? How is `save_xls` called?), I can say that the second assignment of `data = pd.DataFrame()` is going to replace what you've just read into `df` with a new, blank, `DataFrame`.  I'm very sure that's not what you wanted.

Comment: @Abdou Trying to put sheets from sheet1 into one new sheet(let's  say sheet_1),after that put sheets from sheet2 into another new sheet(sheet_2)...and the process goes on and on.

Comment: @cco Trying to put sheets from sheet1 into one new sheet(let's  say sheet_1),after that put sheets from sheet2 into another new sheet(sheet_2)...and the process goes on and on.

Comment: @chenjunjie, I does not seem like you are calling your `save_xls` function anywhere in your script. `save_xls` in written just fine, the issue here (if there is really any) is the `for-loop` before the function definition.